# Можно ли через CSS автоматически изменять вид блока, если он сместился вниз?

Tags: css

Допустим, есть 4 дива, на большом экране они расположены по горизонтали. При уменьшении экрана последний див сползает вниз. Вот можно ли как-то отследить этот момент и изменить вид сползшего элемента? Добавить к нему бордер-топ, например.

Comment: медиа квери используйте

Comment: `@media (max-width: чтототам)`. Про media-запросы не знаете?

Comment: как вариант css grid

Comment: Media хороши, если известна ширина блоков. Но они могут быть произвольной ширины и смещаться вниз при произвольной ширине экрана. Допустим, в блоках может быть контент "А", "Б", "В", "Г", а может быть "Привет участникам XXIV съезда!" в каждом. Соответственно, в первом случае смещение будет только на очень маленьком экране, а во втором случае на довольно большом. С media же, получается изменение для строго фиксированной ширины.

Comment: @Ostet тогда только через javascript координаты блока проверять

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 255px) {
  .elem:last-child {
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

на гридах

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 100px);
}
.container div{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, это ближе всего. Только в grid-template-rows поставить repeat 1, не переносить текст внутри блоков и разобраться, как сделать бордер для смещённых блоков.

Comment: @Ostet механизм вроде как мощный, много различных свойств, думаю можно сделать так как вы хотите, сам недавно только начал изучать, поэтому не подскажу тут

Comment: Да, это уже я сам разберусь, спасибо.

Comment: @Ostet пожалуйста